# Which centripetal force equation should I use for centripetal motion in uniform magnetic field, and why?

Tags: magnetic-fields, centripetal-force

So far I learn two equations, doing the same thing: $$F_c = m\frac{v^2}{r} = qvB$$

It leaves me undecided when a question asks "by what factor is the force increased when velocity is double".

The answer is double, why?

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem in the conceptual understanding here.

The magnetic force is $\vec{F} = q\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$

If the field is constant  if you double the velocity the force would be doubled as well.

But your confusion is that you are not considering the radius in the equation bellow.  It cannot be fixed.

$F = qvB = \frac{mv^2}{r}$

If you double the velocity this relationship still holds, which means that your radius is twice as large. Since

$ r = \frac{m v}{qB}$

Comment: Oh my! You're one of those Clifford algebra wedge product guys! That's okay. Maybe all of us cross-product guys will disappear eventually and then you can change the introductory textbooks. :)

Comment: Actually I like the cross-product as well, but the "wedge" came faster in my mind when I was typing. :P

Comment: Velocity, mass, charge and magnetic field all affect the radius!? I thought radius is an independent variable, like when you hold on to the string it never changes.

Comment: No, they all change the radius. That's how a mass spectrometer works. Or a bubble chamber in particle physics.

Comment: So it's very different from actually spinning it with a string?

Comment: In this case the force would not be constant, since the tension in the spring rises when you speed up the particle. You have the constraint that the particle should follow a orbit with a fixed radius, so if you double the velocity you must have a tension four times higher to keep this trajectory.

Answer (score 3):

I like the answer from @AndreMaizel and I will add another conceptual idea you need to remember. The form $m\frac{v^2}{r}$ is not a real force.  It is a form of $ma$, where the $a$ is a centripetal acceleration. That centripetal acceleration is a "must behave this way" statement, not a "source of force" statement.

As Andre says, the "real force" is the charge interaction with the magnetic field. If the perpendicular velocity is doubled, the force magnitude is doubled. If that is the only force acting, the path radius will double so that $\Sigma\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$ still applies. To emphasize the idea: $\frac{v^2}{r}$ is part of the acceleration side, *not* the force side.

Comment: If i place a charged particle in the magnetic field will it start moving in circle on its own?

Comment: If it is a resting particle it would not experience any magnetic force, so the answer is no.

Comment: Bill, I don't get what you are saying. What is a real force and what is not. If $\frac{v^2}{r}$ is a acceleration then multiplying $m$ makes it force, doesn't it?

Comment: @user132522 The is no "the centripetal force" like there is a gravitational force and a electrostatic force and so on. Instead "centripetal force" is a label applied to some combination of forces---the sum of those pointing inward minus those pointing outward. You figure out this combination when you have circular motion, and ignore it when you don't. Which forces go into the combination depends on the problem. In the case of the free motion of a charged particle in a magnetic field, the only force is the magnetic force and it points in so ***for that problem*** $F_c = F_{magnetic}$.